# How to save the uint32_t mask as a pointer variable?

Tags: c, function, inotify

This `void inotifyFunc()` contains one variable as an argument that is `char *path`. I want to add another variable also that should contain the address of `uint32_t mask` that is basically **ENOENT, IN_CREATE, IN_DELETE, etc** which is present in `inotify_add_watch()` But I don't know how to save `uint32_t mask` as a variable.

My main goal is to call this function in the main function by writing a path, and one command(IN_CREATE, IN_DELETE, etc) at a time that I should assign to the path.

*I hope you understand my question.*

```
void inotifyFunc(char *path){
    monitor.fd = inotify_init();
    if(fcntl(monitor.fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)){
       perror("inotify not initialized: ");
       exit(0);
    }

    monitor.wd = inotify_add_watch(monitor.fd, path, ENOENT);
    if(monitor.wd < 0){
        perror("Sorry");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        printf("Location '%s' is being monitored\n\n", path);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what difficulty you have. Why can't you just add a `uint32_t *mask` parameter to the function? And why does it have to be an address/pointer?

Comment: @kaylum I want to call this function to be in a main function and give the path and the command that I want to assign to the path. Like I want to monitor the path is created or modified or deleted etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get this right

Change:

```
void inotifyFunc(char *path) {
```

To:

```
void inotifyFunc(char *path, uint32_t *mask ) {
```

And then

```
uint32_t mask = ENOENT;
inotifyFunc("....", &mask); // Address of (pointer to) mask
```

Then use

```
monitor.wd = inotify_add_watch(monitor.fd, path, mask);
```

**EDIT**

As I have just read manual page - see comment

Then

```
monitor.wd = inotify_add_watch(monitor.fd, path, *mask);
```

Or

```
void inotifyFunc(char *path, uint32_t mask ) {
```

and

```
 inotifyFunc("....", mask);
```

Comment: Just looked up [inotify_add_watch](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/inotify_add_watch.2.html). See edit.